# Ruby on Rails: Making a printable character sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm planning on building a online character builder for a in-development roleplaying system.  I have a good handle on most of the technical aspects of the builder, but one thing that I keep getting hung up on is how to make a printable character sheet.

For a Rails application, what would be the best way to approach this? Would using a HTML to PDF solution like [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) work the best, or am I better using [prawn](http://prawnpdf.org/) to facilitate generation of the sheet? Or would something completely different do the trick?

I've also seen (in general) character sheet generators overlay information on top of a fixed sheet - is that a good approach, or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: I think I understand your question, but i'm not entirely sure. What I did, is I made a custom print view, and routed a link to it. That print view gets it's own style sheet.

Comment: @bennett_an: I know that this would require either a custom route or adding a special formatting method to the show action for the character, but the actual process of creating the sheet is something that's beyond me.

Comment: You're trying to do something more complicated than just a `.html.erb` file? Because thats all you need.